# How to remove http:// from a website URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, url-routing

Question:

I just stumbled upon:
http://icculus.org/~chunky/writing/inetd

I realized it removes the http://www in front of the URL.
How is that done? 
I am not aware of URL-rewriting being able to do that, or not ?

Comment: `removes the http://`? Are you using Safari? And then again, why would you want to do that?

Comment: On Chrome it does not remove http://

Comment: Not on my computer it doesn't.

Comment: That does not work in any browser like chrome,ie or ff. I'm not sure what browser you're using so that might help.

Comment: I use Chrome 6.0 on Linux and it does. What version do you have?

Comment: There's a difference between not showing and removing. I can't see how it would be possible to remove the protocol or "scheme" from a URL.

Comment: version 6 of chrome doesn't show http:// on any site.

Comment: No, that's what's called a feature.

Comment: Ah, it's the new version it installed yesterday evening / today morning. Ah, it's when you remove the www from the domain. Then it only shows the domainname, because it hides the http:// everywhere. Cool. @BobKaufmann: true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has been experimenting with this feature in the developer version of Chrome. You can read about it at

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41467

http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1601917/google-drops-http-chrome

Comment: And the development version is what I have installed. And obviously, the update was yesterday/today morning. I just noticed when I wanted to copy an URL.

Answer (score 2):

If this happens, it is a browser specific setting and something you don't have control over as a website publisher.